# Keras layer.weights and layer.get_weights() give different values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My Keras model have Dense layers which I need to access the weights and bias values. I can access them using get_weights() method. It returns me expected sized matrices (57X50 for the weights) for weights and biases.

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
```

However the following code snippet gives me same sized matrices with different values.

```
import tensorflow as tf
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(model.layers[0].weights[0]))
```

In the second method bias values are returned as all zeros for all models and weights are different than the output of get_weights() method.

Do you have any idea which way is correct and what exactly the second method does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `init_op`, you initialize all trainable variables, which means zeros for biases and random values for the other weights of your model. Try:

```
import keras.backend as K
with K.get_session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(model.layers[0].weights[0]))
```

Comment: Great, your code block gave same result with get_weights(). Rerunning my second code snippet gives me same reproducible weight results, that's why I thought it could not be random.

Thanks a lot!